# select over several tables with same column names

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to do a query over several tables on Oracle (all of which have the same columns).

Lets suppose column1, column2 and column3 on TABLE_1, TABLE_2 and TABLE_3.

I want to do that on a single statement without using UNION.

Something like:

```
SELECT column1, 
       column2, 
       column3
 FROM (SELECT TABLE_NAME 
         FROM ALL_TABLES 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TABLE_%'
      )
```

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not possible how you are trying to do it. If the result set you are looking for is the union of the tables your best bet in pretty much every case is to just union the tables. You can use dynamic SQL to create the union from the result of a query against ALL_TABLES, but I'd avoid this unless it's really necessary.

Comment: You could write a procedure that builds a string of the query, then runs the string. But the dynamic query you build will do the union. If what you want is a union, use the union as @Error_2646 said.

If you're using this union for a bunch of different queries, you could put it in a view so your specific queries can be shorter.

Comment: If you don't want to "type" `UNION`, then create a view that union them all. Then do your query against the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a poor design. You may create a dynamic `VIEW` and query from that view.

```
DECLARE
     v_sql   VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN


     SELECT
          LISTAGG('SELECT column1,column2,column3 FROM ' || table_name,
               ' UNION ALL ' || CHR(10) ) WITHIN
          GROUP(
               ORDER BY table_name
          )
     INTO v_sql
     FROM all_tables
     WHERE table_name LIKE '%TABLE_%';

     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS ' || v_sql;
END;
/


Select * from my_view;
```

Comment: The dynamic view solution was really interesting. Thank you Kaushik Nayak!

Comment: @Miguel you're welcome. Please accept the answer if you think it helped you.